# Ошибка при добавлении библиотеки SQLite3 в проект

Tags: sqlite3, .net, visual-studio

[image: img error]

Вот такая ошибка дается. Как исправить?

Comment: Для использования SQLite в .NET-е есть [System.Data.SQLite][1] или [C#-SQLite][2]


  [1]: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki
  [2]: http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

Comment: а откуда достать sqlite3.dll для x64??? Я не могу его достать =/ @shad

Comment: sqlite3 вам вообще не нужен, он встроен в System.Data.SQLite, разрядность которого уже важна.

Answer (score 4):

Референс можно добавить только на .NET или COM компонент. Очевидно, sqlite3.dll - нативная библиотека.